# Stop users from entering certain text in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

How would one stop application users from entering certain text inside a text box? For example a blacklist so users can't enter certain usernames etc.

Comment: make control property read only.

Comment: validate the contents against a list of forbidden text.

Comment: Use the textbox keypress event or validate the text when user leaves the control...

Comment: How would one do such things?

Comment: `If myListOfBadStuff.Contains(textbox1.Text) Then...`

Comment: Write a function that returns a Boolean. Pass the text from the textbox into it and validate it against a list.. then in keypress event call the function and check it. If the text matches cancel else it's good.

Comment: MUCH better to match the whole text when they are done to avoid false positives on partial text (ie "admin" might be bad but "administratorDave" might be ok; "ass" versus "assassinX")

Comment: But he wants to stop them... not after according to his question.

Comment: I will post solution when not driving...

Comment: And that's why I wouldn't use contains...

Comment: Is this a Winforms application, Web Forms, WPF, or what?

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the contents of the control when the user leaves it and see if it contains something you don't want in there.

```
 Private Sub textBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles textBox1.Leave
    If txtUserName.Text.Contains("YourBlacklistValue") Then
       txtUserName.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's just an example. Using a hard coded value will also not get what he wanted. I assumed he could handle the string comparison part of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the purpose of the Validating event.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating

    Dim allowedText As String() = New String() {"Hello", "Bye"}

    If allowedText.Count(Function(allowed) allowed.Equals(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) = 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry in TextBox", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub
```

The above code would prevent the TextBox from losing focus unless one of the two strings in the array is entered.

Comment: Alright, what if the user wants to leave the textbox?

Comment: Well if you want the user to be able to leave the TextBox without a valid answer then leave e.Cancel as False. That is what prevents the loss of focus, the Cancel property.

Answer (score 0):

This will work just great, handle it on the `KeyPress` event that way we can make sure it's not even entered. Also it's a function that you can use anywhere you want for any textbox keypress event. Also the arrList I declared was for example ONLY, you can pull a list from a db and add items to an array and such or predefine a list yourself... This is tried and tested.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

Private arrList As String() = {"SillyBobbyWalt", "BobbyWalt", "SillyEngineer", "Engineers", "123", "Bobby123"}

Public Shared Function IsTextAllowed(ByVal text As String, ByVal strChar As String, ByVal arrList As Array) As Boolean
    Dim blnAllowed As Boolean = True

    For Each item As String In arrList
        If CStr(text & strChar.ToLower) = item Then
            blnAllowed = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return blnAllowed
End Function

Private Sub txtValue_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtValue.KeyPress
    If Not IsTextAllowed(CStr(txtValue.Text), e.KeyChar.ToString, arrList) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom control.  Handling the KeyPress event internally to trap the Enter key and check for a valid user name, is one way to do this:

```
Public Class ValidatingTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Private BlackList As List(Of String)
    Private GoodList As List(Of String)
    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler Me.KeyPress, AddressOf Key_Press
    End Sub
    Private Sub Key_Press(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) Then
            If BlackList.Contains(Text) OrElse Not GoodList.Contains(Text) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid User")
                Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

With this pattern it's easy to implement whichever method you want that stays hidden inside your control.

Comment: Nice example, but contains can create false positive results. Also when adding handlers, make sure to remove them. Its not fun when unhandled memory starts climbing. Another note, not everyone will press enter, they may tab or click out of the textbox...

Comment: Since contains is acting on a list there are no false positives.  The handler gets disposed when the control gets disposed.  As my comments indicate this is presented more as an example of what can be done.